# Flutter _JsonQuerySnapshot' has no instance method '[]'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I have collection for Users and groups, I want to display list of last update groups. But, the user uid must be stay in member field(array) of group Collection.

So, I use StreamBuilder and get snapshot like this,

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("groups")
                .orderBy('LastUpdate', descending: true)
                .where(
                  "members",
                  isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
                )
                .snapshots()
```

group collection {

- LastUpdate filed type is timestamp,
- members filed type is array
  }

There is a screenshot of firebase database group collection,

[image]

This is fullcode, When it run, it shows a error

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("groups")
            .orderBy('LastUpdate', descending: true)
            .where(
              "members",
              isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
            )
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(
              '${snapshot.error}',
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            );
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 2, // <---- want to set length of groups - user have
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Text(
                    snapshot.data['groupName'],
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.white),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.white),
            );
          }
        });
```

Error says -

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
Class '_JsonQuerySnapshot' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: []("groupName")
```

Main problem is that. and other thing is want to set count of groups user have. I set above code `itemCount: 2,`.

Please help to complete my code.

Comment: could you print("data = ${snapshot.data}") inside snapshot.hasData condition before return that padding and show me the result?

Comment: It shows --- > data = Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'

Comment: good, could you print this: print("data = ${snapshot.data.data()}")

Comment: This time show  (error) --- > Class '_JsonQuerySnapshot' has no instance method 'data'.
Receiver: Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: data()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `data` on stream result you access to the QuerySnapshot inside that so you need to call `.docs` to access the document inside that and after that run `ListView` on those `docs`, so instead of use `snapshot.data` use `snapshot.data.docs`:

```
 ListView.builder(
    itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      var data = snapshot.data.docs[index].data();
      return Text(
        data['groupName'],
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.white),
      );
    },
  ),
```

also replace `isEqualTo` with `arrayContains`:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("groups")
        .orderBy('LastUpdate', descending: true)
        .where( "members", arrayContains: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid, )
        .snapshots(),
```

Comment: It works. but not display anything.  Firebase group collection has groups, this member uid incuded in member array

Comment: could you print("data = {snapshot.data.docs[index]}") inside itemBuilder before return Text?

Comment: not printing anything, So, I print("hey ya yayayayayaa"); before return Text, It also not printing anything

Comment: First time I run it, It says---- The query requires an index. You can create it here: gave an link. I created it. It will be problem?

Comment: check my last update, see that could helps you?

Comment: Could you remove orderBy('LastUpdate', descending: true) from your stream and see what is going on?!

Comment: It works when comment -- > .where()

Comment: I think I am wrong, checking one item from list like this. -->  .where(
        "members",
        isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
      )

Comment: Yeah I think can’t find any thing equal to that uid

Comment: Could you print(“member=${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid})

Comment: It shows ----> member=USTZLhvpv7OnSGnk8cRNKIT69Bq1

Comment: As you see this member is not in your firebase list that you add in image

Comment: No, he is in. The only member of the group show in picture is him. index 0 is USTZLhvpv7OnSGnk8cRNKIT69Bq1

Comment: Maybe  the problem because the index i created in firebase.  Details of them --> ( Fields indexed) members Ascending LastUpdate Descending

Comment: Finally found it. .where(
   "members",
   arrayContains: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
) .. 

Thank you so much for your support. You made my day.

Comment: yeah arrayContains do the work. glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

`.snapshot()` return a Stream of an instance of `QuerySnapshot` as you can do when you use `.get()` you can access the result (the list of docs) by the `.docs` property.

Said that your code can be changed like the following:

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("groups")
          .orderBy('LastUpdate', descending: true)
          .where(
        "members",
        isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
      )
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(
            '${snapshot.error}',
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final docs = snapshot.data.docs;
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text(
                  docs[index].data['groupName'],
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.white),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.white),
          );
        }
      });
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you. But, It not display anything. Firebase group collection has groups, this member uid incuded in member array.                                                                              First time I run it, It says---- The query requires an index. You can create it here: gave an link. I created it. It will be problem?

Comment: in the error message you have a link copy-paste this link into the browser where you are logged in to Firebase and it generates the index automatically for you.